# Vite css response configuration

Tags: css, vite

When i'm asking a css-file this way

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/test/data/tst.css?', false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","text/css,*/*")
xhr.send();
console.log(xhr.response);
```

Everything is ok.

```
#ggg{font-size: 50px;}
```

But when this way

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/test/data/tst.css?', false);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","*/*")
xhr.send();
console.log(xhr.response);
```

The response looks like

```
import { createHotContext as __vite__createHotContext } from "/@vite/client";import.meta.hot = __vite__createHotContext("/test/data/tst.css");import { updateStyle as __vite__updateStyle, removeStyle as __vite__removeStyle } from "/@vite/client"
const __vite__id = "/home/user/dev/project/front/test/data/tst.css"
const __vite__css = "#ggg{font-size: 50px;}"
__vite__updateStyle(__vite__id, __vite__css)
import.meta.hot.accept()
export default __vite__css
import.meta.hot.prune(() => __vite__removeStyle(__vite__id))
```

Is there a way to configure vite to respond in the second example like in the first example?

Answer (score 1):

Because vite has two strategies on css:

- if a css request include `text/css` header, vite will inject css style code into  directly, so you get the first result.
- otherwise, vite will add a `.js` extension to css file, and treat it as a js, so you will see the second result.

if you want to know more details, please see [source code](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/vite/src/node/server/middlewares/transform.ts#L162)

Comment: So is there config option for vite to not add .js extension for a *.css file in a certain folder?

Comment: @Roman you can treat css files as static assets, put them into /public, then you can get it via GET request.

Comment: i can, but response is still .js

Comment: @Roman sorry  to reply so late, and I misunderstood your problem, your problem is not static assets, the key point is `text/css` MIME Type, vite will add a suffix `?direct` to css file with 'text/css' MIME type, and all css file will pass to vite css plugin, if with `?direct`, it will return the first result directly, if without `?direct`, it will return the second result. see [css plugin](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/main/packages/vite/src/node/plugins/css.ts#L194)